# Cordova Plugins not Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have the following issue. I'm using Cordova. I have added "**ngCrodova**" ahead of "**cordova.js**"

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Added the plugins I needed. But in cordova object I am not having plugins attribute. Where as `cordova plugin ls` shows the list of included plugins.

[Image of Cordova object and List of plugins I have in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImNKE.png)

What am I missing? Help please.

Comment: Shouldn't the sequence of inclusion of scripts be other way around?? Cordova.js first and then ng-cordova??

Comment: Following link https://devdactic.com/local-notifications-ionic/ tells

"Now the ngCordova JavaScript library must be added to your index.html file like the following:

<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

It is very important that the above line appears above the cordova.js script, otherwise you’re going to experience strange results."

Comment: Fair that!! So then can you post the code where you are using the cordova object?

Comment: check plugins folder.. and add dependencies in `fetch.json` and `plugin.json` and build using CLI.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary
$scope.add = function () {
        var alarmTime = new Date();
        alarmTime.setMinutes(alarmTime.getMinutes() + 1);
        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: "1234",
            date: alarmTime,
            message: "X",
            title: "X",
            autoCancel: true,
            sound: null
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("The notification has been set");
        });
    };

Comment: @atulquest93 I have the my dependencies in my plugin folder. And I have added in json. Didnt work.

Comment: check `config.xml` if you plugin is getting updated there.

Comment: @atulquest93 Plugin is showing to be installed there with green tick mark.

Comment: search for cordova_plugins.js file in www of assets folder if its android platform

Comment: @RafiqAhmed Are you invoking the plugin code inside cordova device ready listener function? Else it will not work as cordova will not be loaded completely by then

Comment: I'm not used to Angular (so I don't know if ng-cordova should change it); but the plugin list that you've shown doesn't put their JS calls at `cordova.plugins`, for example `splashscreen` put it at `window.navigator.splashscreen`, or `device` put it at `window.device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check cordova_plugins.js file which is inside assets folder. it show all plugins installed in project. check below image for reference[image]